# Appcelerator Label width and height determination

Tags: android, mobile, width, titanium, label

I'm developing mobile application at Appcelerator Titanium. I'm creating few labels with text and i need to determine width of labels before creating them.  I know everything about they params (text, fontSize, fontWeight, etc). How can i determine their widths? Application for android.

Comment: You cant determine their true widths until after they have been created. Unless you create them offscreen and then add them in.

Comment: Ditto -- the "why" is a bit more important to answering you here than the capability. What are you trying to do with the labels?

Comment: I have a text and i need to insert in this text an image, or to set color of a part of this text, to place a controls correctly i need to know width of a label with known text. I don't want to use webview.

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck with the [StyledLabel module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4981?1140416519), which is available for iOS and Android. This allows a bit of styling, via HTML, from within a label that acts much like a standard `Ti.UI.Label` control. It's not perfect and will be a little heavier than a standard `Label`, but should be more lightweight than a `WebView`. One of the biggest advantages to using `StyledLabel` is, unlike a `WebView`, it expands and contracts to fill the contenet, whereas a `WebView` needs a defined width.

If you're just building for iOS then I'd suggest that module, but if you're building for Android, you don't need it as Android `Label` controls can take some simple HTML. I'm currently using it in a production project, and for the most part it works great, just not well from within `TableView`s.

The reason I mention using HTML is that it might be better to use a single control that can take a little styling, than multiple controls in order to get the appearance of a string of text which has some sections coloured differently.

Maybe combining that with the control's `postlayout` event will help you further, as you should then be able to get the control's width and height, either via the `width` and `height` properties, or via the `size` property (`size.width` and `size.height`). You can then position your controls based on the label's position.